# Работа приложения при выключенном экране

Tags: android, android-service

Хотелось бы узнать, что использовать для того, чтобы приложение могло бы работать в режиме "сна" (при нажатии кнопки выключения)?
Пробовал использовать класс Service, но при выключении экрана он "глохнет". Знаю, что не достает какой-то важной части (в плане разрешения доступа или чего-то подобного), но сам не смог найти.
Собственно код:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    someTask();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public void someTask() {
   ......
}
}
```

В в Main-е вызываю сервис при открытии приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю класс Service подходит для вашей задачи.  Было бы неплохо если бы к вопросу еще код какой то показали!

Comment: странно выглядит норм, возможно пропустили какой то permission в Manifest.xml

Comment: "могло бы работать в режиме "сна"- как же я рад что ввели doze mode)

Comment: @gcoder,  ввели, спустя 7 версий)

Comment: попробуйте добавить <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Comment: Да нет, все работает отлично, когда сворачиваешь приложение, проблемы возникают тогда, когда нажимаешь кнопку выключения. Покопался немного, попробую использовать Foreground Service, он используется для работы плееров (воспроизведение при выключенном экране). Дам знать, если поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И это правильно. Так и задумано, чтоб при заблокированном экране батарея устройства не разряжалась.

Если, всё же, хотите, то используйте WakeLock и [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html):

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakeLock"); 
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо. Только ругался на первую строчку () на context.get...  , исправил на:
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

Comment: @РусланАхпашев `context` - это текущий контекст. Если вы это делаете внутри `Activity`, то это `this`.